# Can't install Laravel via Composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem Composer and Laravel. I found a lot of similar topic but it doesn't work. So when I try install Laravel it will show me:
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.22)

> - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.22): Loading from cache Created project in sadsa
>
>   > @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   >     dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   >     resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
>   Problem 1
>
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2,
>       6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5].
>
>   To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>     files:
>
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

When I try install it globally, I have this but I can't use Laravel new something command:

> Changed current directory to /home/michal/.composer
>   Using version ^1.5 for laravel/installer
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files
>   How I said I found a lot of topic but nothing works like install mbstring and so on.

Comment: maybe you can try using homestead https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead, all the Laravel requirement is ready to use in the VM

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me it is mainly focus at message `requires ext-dom`. Possible work around i can suggest is to install following packages:

- php-xml
- php-common

Or you can try with specific php version as follow:

- php7.0-xml
- php7.0-common

**for php 7.0**

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and PHP 7.1 is running well using

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

If you are using another version of PHP, for example: 7.0 can change it to

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Don't forget to alwasy restart web server, for example in Ubuntu you can type in terminal:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

After that you can try run composer again. Hope this helps.